# How to overcome "Permission denied" running C program even after "chmod +x"?

Tags: permissions, compiling, executable, chmod, c

After compiling a C program on Ubuntu 10.10, after executing `chmod +x ./a.out`, I am still getting `bash: ./a.out: Permission denied`. How can I run my new executable?

Comment: Are you the owner of the file?  You're not building as root, are you (using sudo, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason is that you are compiling on a file system that has been mounted with the `noexec` option.

Run `mount -l` to see the options that file systems are mounted with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling the program and running the executable file on an external drive or something similar, move the file to Desktop and recompile and run it there.